# How to hide csv content in awk script

Tags: csv, awk

First of all, thank you in advance. I am struggling to get the following answer using an awk script:

Input: **gawk -f script.awk file.csv**

(I cannot use tail method at the end. Only the above.)

Desired Output:

***The average age of 20 people who speak Spanish is 29.55 years.***

Actual Output:

[ActualOutput Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXty2.png)

So basically, I only want to hide or eliminate that information and only showing the Desired output.

My script is the following (also in the picture):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{contador=0;total=0}
FS=",";$4 ~/.*spanish.*/||$5~/.*spanish.*// {contador++;total=total+$3} 
END{
printf("\nThe average age of %d people who speak Spanish is %.2f years.\n",contador,total/contador)
}
```

Here I also leave the csv file:

```
user,gender,age,native_lang,other_lang
0,M,19,finnish,english swedish german
1,M,30,urdu,english 
2,F,26,finnish,english swedish german
3,M,20,finnish,english french swedish 
4,F,20,finnish,english swedish 
5,F,29,finnish,english 
6,F,23,swedish,finnish english 
7,F,19,swedish,finnish english french 
8,F,25,finnish,english swedish german russian french estonian
9,F,27,finnish,english italian swedish spanish french
10,F,20,finnish,english 
11,F,26,finnish,english swedish
12,F,27,finnish,english swedish french spanish
13,F,30,finnish,english russian swedish 
14,F,28,finnish,english swedish spanish german 
15,M,34,finnish,swedish english german spanish russian 
16,F,29,finnish,english swedish french spanish estonian 
17,F,19,swedish,finnish english french korean
18,M,27,finnish,english swedish german russian spanish dutch
19,F,27,finnish,english swedish russian 
20,F,26,finnish,english swedish 
21,M,23,finnish,english swedish
22,M,30,english,finnish 
23,F,25,finnish,swedish english spanish 
24,F,21,finnish,english swedish spanish 
25,F,26,finnish,english swedish
26,M,20,polish,english spanish finnish 
27,M,25,finnish,english french 
28,F,21,russian,finnish english french 
29,F,28,finnish,english swedish
30,F,19,finnish,english swedish french spanish 
31,O,40,finnish,swedish english german russian lithuanian portuguese
32,F,22,finnish,swedish english french
33,M,26,spanish,english german french
34,F,20,finnish,swedish english german
35,F,21,finnish,english german swedish russian italian
36,F,22,finnish,english swedish
37,F,22,finnish,english swedish spanish
38,F,20,finnish,english italian swedish
39,F,29,finnish,english swedish italian french
40,F,20,finnish,english swedish german french
41,F,44,finnish,english swedish french italian german spanish latin portuguese russian dutch danish basque
42,F,31,finnish,english swedish spanish
43,F,23,finnish,english swedish korean
44,F,19,finnish,english swedish german
45,M,20,finnish,english
46,M,20,swedish,finnish english spanish
47,F,39,finnish,english swedish german korean
48,F,26,finnish,english swedish spanish
49,F,34,french,finnish english spanish russian swedish german hebrew
50,F,56,spanish,english
51,F,50,spanish,english
52,F,25,spanish dutch,english
```

Sorry for the bad text format, it is my first question here in Stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="," }
     NR>1 && /spanish/{ c++; sum+=$3 }
     END{ print "The average age of",c,"people who speak Spanish is",sum/c,"years." }' file
```

Output:

```
The average age of 20 people who speak Spanish is 29.55 years.
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – **FS**, OFS, RS, ORS, **NR**, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)